# When ever I enter wrong credential to login my node model crashes

Tags: node.js, nodes, node-modules, mern

I am trying to make a login route in node.js but when ever I enter wrong credential my application crashes

This is my Login route, Please tell me what I am doing wrong

```
router.post("/login", async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const user = await User.findOne({ email: req.body.email });
    !user && res.status(400).json("User Not exist!");

    const validated = await bcrypt.compare(req.body.password, user.password);
    !validated && res.status(400).json("Invalid Password!");

    const { password, ...others } = user._doc;
    res.status(200).json(others);
  } catch (err) {
    res.status(500).json(err);
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you just add a return before the responses and make your code cleaner the problem is that when you write res.status(400)... the code will continue to the next steps and the app will crash so your code should be like that

```
router.post("/login", async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const user = await User.findOne({ email: req.body.email });
    if (!user) {
      return res.status(400).json("User Not exist!");
    }

    const validated = await bcrypt.compare(req.body.password, user.password);
    if (!validated) {
      return res.status(400).json("Invalid Password!");
    }

    const { password, ...others } = user._doc;
    return res.status(200).json(others);
  } catch (err) {
    return res.status(500).json(err);
  }
});
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).